# To print the whole html page

Tags: html, printing-web-page

I have a button and use `window.print()` to print the page ,

but it is printing only a singe page of what is visible in the viewport. 
However the page is long enough to fill 5 pages.

How can I get it to print the whole page?

Comment: Sorry, just to get this clear, you do mean you have only one HTML page, but it is tall enough to fill five sheets of paper?

Comment: Html page is upto 5 pages long ,but when i use this method it prints only that part which is seen on sceen only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate css file for print whole page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>
```

You can define following width in your css file.

```
body, html, #wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your browser.

window.print() just starts the browser print dialog, if you select to only print the first page there, then that is what happens.

Comment: Is there any other way to print my whole HTML page? tjnks in advance

Comment: @user1260967 Obviously: yes. Wait for the print dialog to appear and check 'print all pages'. The problem is not with the window.print() command but with your personal selection on your computer in this situation. window.print() WILL print the whole page.

Comment: I am using microsoft on note ,after selecting the "all page" ,result is still same . thnxs for previous suggestion!

Comment: @user1260967 then please post a link to your site (if its public) or some code to pastebin.com (and a link to it then here) so one can see what is the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Like Angelo here said, it really is all about what you select to print. You shouldn't have any problems with it, worked for me in this way:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Click to Print This Page</a>
```

Still any problems?